# Made an error solving a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Can anybody explain to me what I did wrong here?
I am working on practice problems for my linear algebra course. The problem in question is as follows:

Suppose the system below is consistent for all possible values of f and g. What can you say about the coefﬁcients c and d? Justify your answer.

$x_1+3x_2=f$

$cx_1+dx_2=g$

My first idea was to simply solve for d and c in terms of f and g:

$x_1+3x_2=f \implies \frac{x_1}{f}+\frac{3x_2}{f}=1$

$cx_1+dx_2=g \implies \frac{cx_1}{g}+\frac{dx_2}{g}=1$

Then these can be set equal to each other:

$\frac{x_1}{f}+\frac{3x_2}{f}=\frac{cx_1}{g}+\frac{dx_2}{g}$

$\implies \frac{1}{f}=\frac{c}{g}, \frac{3}{f}=\frac{d}{g}$

$\implies \frac{g}{f}=c, \frac{3g}{f}=d$

$\therefore d=3c$

I believed this answer would hold true, at least for nonzero values of f and g. However, row reduction on the system shows the exact opposite:

$ \begin{array}{lcr}
\mbox{1} & 3 & f \\
\mbox{c} & d & g \\
\end{array}\ $

$\implies$

$ \begin{array}{lcr}
\mbox{1} & 3 & f \\
\mbox{0} & d-3c & g-fc \\
\end{array}\ $

This matrix suggests that $g\neq3c$ *except* when f and g are zero. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my first approach? Looking at it, I can tell that my answer is wrong (unless $g=cf$), but I don't see what is wrong with the algebra.

Comment: You’ve reached the opposite of the correct conclusion with your first method: when $d=3c$, the system cannot be consistent for all $f$ and $g$. You’ve also got some potential divisions by zero that you haven’t dealt with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't jump from$$\frac{x_1}f+\frac{3x_2}f=\frac{cx_1}g+\frac{dx_2}g\tag1$$to$$\frac1f=\frac cg\text{ and }\frac3f=\frac dg.$$You could if the equality $(1)$ was true for every $x_1$ and every $x_2$, but you are assuming it only for *some* $x_1$ and *some* $x_2$.